# Unable to see thumb drive through file manager

Tags: files, permissions, chmod

I am using EndeavorOS with i3 and am trying to put stuff on a thumb drive, but Thunar file manager isn't seeing it. When I run `fdisk -l` and `lsusb` I see the thumb drive, but it doesn't show up in Thunar.

I tried `mount /dev/sdc`, but I get the response `mount: /dev/sdc: can't find in /etc/fstab`. I also tried `chmod -R 0777 /dev/sdc` which runs without error but nothing changes. I am not really sure what to do at this point. Below is the useful bit of my output for `fdisk` and `lsusb`.

`lsusb`: `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 154b:00ed PNY USB 3.1 FD`

`fdisk`:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 28.91 GiB, 31042043904 bytes, 60628992 sectors
Disk model: USB 3.1 FD      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 304380E4-7F38-4C05-9262-5A90B5275272
```

Comment: Are there no partitions on the thumb drive or is the part only missing in your fdisk output?

Comment: It doesn't have any partitions that I'm seeing.

Comment: Then you need to create at least one. Maybe use `gparted` to create a partition and filesystem.

Comment: @Freddy You were correct. I someone totally missed that it didn't have any partitions. Feel free to open an answer so I can mark it correct! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please feel free to self-answer your question. You need the reputation more than I do.

Answer (score 0):

With help from Freddy in the comments I found the issue was that the thumb drive didn't have a partition. Creating one with GParted solved the problem!